# Wireless not working in Kali 1.1.0 on Alienware 15

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I'm new to this and i created a usb to run kali live on my Alienware 15. Once I get in, the ethernet is working fine but if I use the iwconfig command, it says "no wireless extensions" Can someone help me out with this as I need the wireless working properly. My wireless card according to the Alienware website is the Killer 1525 802.11ac 2x2 WiFi

Comment: What shows up from ' ifconfig -a' ?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:e6:d7:25:5f:aa  
          inet addr:50.89.118.124  Bcast:50.89.118.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::36e6:d7ff:fe25:5faa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5011 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4033 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4866221 (4.6 MiB)  TX bytes:482683 (471.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:18

Comment: @linuxdev2013 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:960 (960.0 B)  TX bytes:960 (960.0 B)